# Working with a cookie-free sub-domain using Symfony2/3

Tags: symfony, cookies, routes

I have two sub-domains:
www.example.com and static.example.com
The root domain example.com redirects to www.example.com.

How can I restrict cookies to www.example.com in Symfony2/3 and make static.example.com free of cookies. I didn't find any cookies section in config.yml.

How can I specify a specific subdomain when using the functions:
href="{{ asset('favicon.png') }}"
href="{{ path('blog_show') }}"
$this->generateUrl('blog_show',array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));

PS: I also have full-control on Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
framework:
    templating:      
        assets_base_urls:
            http: static.example.com
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls

#### Edit:

You can group assets into packages, to specify different base URLs for them:

```
framework:
    templating:
        packages:
            avatars:
                base_urls: 'static.example.com'
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html#packages

For rest question: url generation, I'm not sure what mean cookie free route path.

Comment: The config you supplied will impact all the generated URLs as I can guess, sometimes I will create URLs which use www.example.com and other times static.example.com, may be there's a per-path-function-call alternative ?

Comment: Sorry for my late resonse, the correct URL is http://symfony.com/doc/master....#packages. For cookie free subdomaine (static...), I want to prevent sending cokkies headers in the request to optimize the response time, becase when fetching assets we don't need cookies at all.

Comment: Yes for assets thats true, but I don't understand cookie free domain for routes as you described:  `path('blog_show')`

Comment: Ok for routes, the question is how to specify a specific subdomain when routing (static subdomain for assets), the base_urls can be a good solution, now I need to instruct Symfony to avoid sending cookies to the subdomain static to make HTTPs transactions quicker. I know it's possible in the basic php function with $path parameter: setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] ), but how to accomplish this with Symfony's HTTP Foundation API or with a config entry ?

Comment: You can set cookie domain in config: `cookie_domain: 'main.domain.com'`